# Rails simple_form gem is adding a green border to inputs that are pre-populated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4, simple-form

I am having a problem with the rails simple_form gem. I am using bootstrap 4 along with it.

I have installed the gem by adding `gem 'simple_form'` to the Gemfile. I have also run the generator via `rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap`.

Simple Form works almost perfectly in my app. Here is an example using a model called 'Store' that has one string attribute: 'name'.

```
<%= simple_form_for @store do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn-primary" %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", stores_url, class: %w[btn btn-danger] %>
<% end %>
```

The only problem I'm having with this code is that when the form is used for the update page, simple_form adds an '.is-valid' class to the input element which causes bootstrap to add a green border to the field. This does not happen when the field is not pre-filled such as when using the form for the 'new' action.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the intended behavior. What is the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb` you have a few different blocks that start with `config.wrapper`. You can remove any reference to `valid_class: 'is-valid'` from them so that it is no longer included in your form inputs. i.e....

Change this

```
config.wrappers :vertical_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'form-group-invalid', valid_class: 'form-group-valid' do |b|
  ...
  b.use :input, class: 'form-control', error_class: 'is-invalid', valid_class: 'is-valid'
  ...
end
```

To this (by removing `valid_class`)

```
config.wrappers :vertical_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'form-group-invalid' do |b|
  ...
  b.use :input, class: 'form-control', error_class: 'is-invalid'
  ...
end
```

And you can remove references to `error_class` as well if you don't want that included.

Comment: Yay! This is perfect. I do have one question, though. How come the file has a comment at the top saying not to edit it directly?

Comment: It's recommended to follow their [guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#custom-components) for creating custom wrappers (by creating seperate component files and including them in the intializer). However, in your case, you want to remove the default class (`is-valid`) globally, so editing the initializer directly is fine.